# What is the best way to save connection strings in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm writing a content delivery system, which saves data on other companies ftp-server. For that I have to store the connection infos, like host, username, password, … in a database.

I will hash the data and thinking about to save the salts in a config file out of root. But I don't like the idea to write the data to a file.

Is there any better solution to save the salts?

Comment: If this is your concern, [there is no need to secure the salt](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/17435).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it by ssh keys. Client company will generate a pair of keys and upload their public key into your system. Your system can - then - use this public key to establish connection and do it's job.

This way it is easy for them to disable such public key (without changing passwords in all of their related systems). They can set public keys to expire in certain time, and so on. They (clients) should feel more safely about that.

You can store public keys in database, or in files, but using database approach should be easier to protect those keys. Any way... That's your responsibility to protect your database. And that's - how to do it - a totally different question :)

---

I'm sure you can find information about authenticating using ssh keys for any php framework, and in raw php you can also do it using: [ssh2_auth_pubkey_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php) for example.